# Rails Redis setting maxmemory and maxmemory-policy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, redis

I'm trying to set `maxmemory` and `maxmemory-policy` in my cache_store configuration of my Rails app.

I did the following in my production.rb file:

```
  redis_url = "redis://localhost:6379/0"
  config.cache_store = :redis_store, redis_url, { :expires_in => 4.weeks ,
                                                  :namespace => 'rails-cache',
                                                  :maxmemory => '25gb',
                                                  'maxmemory-policy' => 'volatile-ttl'}
```

But the maxmemory doesn't seam to be working. When I do `Rails.cache.methods` I don't get any methods about `memory` or `max`.

I dont' see any examples on the web for Rails, the closest thing was [handling redis maxmemory situations with rails when using rails caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9471684/handling-redis-maxmemory-situations-with-rails-when-using-rails-caching) but it doesn't give any examples.

I also cloned and grepped for `maxmemory` in the the `redis-rb` gem (https://github.com/redis/redis-rb), but nothing comes up. So it seem like it has not been implemented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set the cache store to use redis-rb, and it hasn't implemented maxmemory, I don't see why it'd work.

In particular, it seems like you configure redis's maxmemory in the redis server's config, so I don't think you can do it through a connecting client (ie. redis-rb).

Comment: Yeah after I asked the question I read through their code and realized they haven't implemented maxmemory & maxmemory-policy yet. I wasn't 100% sure before I asked the question. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you'd have to set it in redis.conf (or your AWS configuraton) http://redis.io/topics/lru-cache